# Remove original data from regression_forest without changing the type to "list"

Tags: r, list, types, typeerror, random-forest

I would like to estimate a regression_forest with the grf package and remove the original data that is stored in the regression_forest output for data protection reasons.

The problem is that when I remove the data, R doesn't recognize the object as a regression_forest anymore and therefore throws an error.

Does anyone know how to go around this problem?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(grf)

# Train a standard regression forest.
n <- 50
p <- 10
X <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), n, p)
Y <- X[, 1] * rnorm(n)
r.forest <- regression_forest(X, Y)

# Remove the original data
r.forest <- r.forest[-c(18,19)]

# Predict using the forest.
X.test <- matrix(0, 101, p)
X.test[, 1] <- seq(-2, 2, length.out = 101)
r.pred <- predict(r.forest, X.test)
```

The last line causes the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("predict") :  no applicable method for 'predict'
> applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: I'm using the grf package. 
Sorry, I've added that in the code now.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the original data? Have you read the [document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grf/grf.pdf) of the package? Maybe there is an argument for the function that does that

Comment: I want to share the model without sharing the original data that was used to estimate it. 
Unfortunately I couldn't find any information about how to do that in the documentation. That's why I have created this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `predict` function seems to need to know the dimensions of the original data, but from what I can tell it doesn't need the data itself.

If you convert the original data stored in the model object to NA, then the predictions seem unaffected.

```
# Get original predictions
r.pred.original <- predict(r.forest, X.test)

# Convert stored data to NA
r.forest$X.orig[!is.na(r.forest$X.orig)] <- NA

# Get new predictions
r.pred.new <- predict(r.forest, X.test)

# r.pred.original and r.pred.new are the same
```